# If no deja cumplir una segunda condición

Tags: java, condiciones, java-awt

estoy empezando a aprender sobre objetos en java (por a la uni) por ahora solo puntos y rectángulos. hay una consigna que pide lo siguiente:

Crear un método **public static boolean estaContenido(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)**
-El método debe indicar si el rectangulo r1 está contenido completamente dentro del rectángulo r2-

y lo hice, este es mi código:

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Objetos07 {

    public static boolean estaContenido(Rectangle rec1, Rectangle rec2) {
        Point puntoA=new Point(rec1.x,rec1.y);
        Point puntoB=new Point(rec1.width+rec1.x,rec1.height+rec1.y);
        System.out.print(rec2+"\n"+puntoA+"\n"+puntoB+"\n");

        if(Objetos04.estaDentro(puntoA, rec2)) {
        //el metodo estaDentro me dice si un punto esta dentro de un rectangulo, funciona correctamente
            System.out.print("El punto A esta adentro\n");
        }
        if(Objetos04.estaDentro(puntoB, rec2)) {
            System.out.print("El punto B esta adentro\n");
        }

        if(Objetos04.estaDentro(puntoA, rec2) && Objetos04.estaDentro(puntoB, rec2)) {
            System.out.print("A y B estan adentro");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {//programa principal
        Rectangle rectangulo1=new Rectangle(-2,-2,-1,-1);
        Rectangle rectangulo2=new Rectangle(-1,-1,-3,-3);

        System.out.print(estaContenido(rectangulo1, rectangulo2));
    }

}
```

Cuando lo pruebo, el primer if (para verificar puntoA) funciona, o sea entra en el if e imprime la siguiente linea, pero ya al segundo if (para verificar puntoB) y el tercero (de ambos puntos) no entra y no sé por qué. Ya verifique y ambos puntos están dentro del rectángulo, por lo que deberia entrar en todos los if. Incluso si comento el primer if, el segundo ahora si funciona, es como si el método pudiera entrar solo a un if y luego ignorara el resto, por más que sean válidos.
Espero haberme explicado bien.

EDIT- Agrego el código de estaDentro():

```
public static boolean estaDentro(Point p,Rectangle rec) {
    if(rec.width<0) {
        rec.x=-rec.x;
        rec.width=-rec.width;
        p.x=-p.x;
    }
    if(rec.height<0) {
        rec.y=-rec.y;
        rec.height=-rec.height;
        p.y=-p.y;
    }

    if(p.x>rec.x && p.x<(rec.width+rec.x)) {
        if(p.y>rec.y && p.y<rec.height+rec.y) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Agrega el código de la función estaDentro()

Comment: @crrlos agregado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de la función `estaDentro()` el objeto `rec` tiene una propiedad `x`, cuando se ejecuta la línea `rec.x=-rec.x;` el valor de `rex.x` ahora es negativo y asumo eso está bien para efectos del cálculo que se hará. El problema es que ese objeto `rec` al que se le modificó su propiedad x es el mismo objeto que fue pasado como parámetro, quiere decir que desde la función se modificó el valor del objeto que está afuera de esta.

Cuando se vuelve a llamar la función `estaDentro()` y se le pasa de nuevo el objeto `rec`, su valor de `x` será negativo, y dentro de la función se hará positivo y los cálculos ya no van a funcionar.

Para evitar esos problemas se puede crear un clon de los parámetros dentro de la función para que no se modifiquen los objetos originales:

```
public static boolean estaDentro(Point p0,Rectangle rec0) {

    // clon de los objetos originales para evitar su modificación
    Point p = new Point(rec0.x, rec0.y);
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(/*inicializar con los valores de rec0*/);

    if(rec.width<0) {
        rec.x=-rec.x;
        rec.width=-rec.width;
        p.x=-p.x;
    }
    if(rec.height<0) {
        rec.y=-rec.y;
        rec.height=-rec.height;
        p.y=-p.y;
    }

    if(p.x>rec.x && p.x<(rec.width+rec.x)) {
        if(p.y>rec.y && p.y<rec.height+rec.y) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente el problema era ese, no sabia que al modificar a un objeto desde un metodo sus valores se cambian globalmente. esto no sucede con otras variables mas comunes, estaba acostumbrado a eso. gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes dos Rectangulos llamemoslos rectangulo1 y rectangulo2, entonces con el metodo estaContenido( necesita del metodo hacerPos) determina si rectangulo2 esta contenido en rectangulo1, seria:

```
        public boolean estaContenido(Rectangle rectangulo1,Rectangle rectangulo2){
             Rectangle rec1=hacerPos(rectangulo1);
             Rectangle rec2=hacerPos(rectangulo2);
             return (rec1.x<rec2.x)&&(rec1.y<rec2.y)&&(rec1.x+Math.abs(rec1.width)>rec2.x+Math.abs(rec2.width))&&(rec1.y+Math.abs(rec1.height)>rec2.y+Math.abs(rec2.height));

        }

        public Rectangle hacerPos(Rectangle rec) {
          Rectangle ret=rec;
          if(ret.width<0) {
            ret=new Rectangle(ret.x+ret.width,ret.y,-ret.width,ret.height);
          }
          if(rec.height<0) {
            ret=new Rectangle(ret.x,ret.y+ret.height,ret.width,-ret.height);
          }
          return ret;
        }
```

Espero te sirva.

Que Dios todo poderoso los bendiga

Comment: Edite mi primera respuesta, mil disculpas, ya que no sabia que width y height podian tomar valores negativos. En esta solución corregí el problema.